# Get a table of org-mode file from elisp to be passed to R

Tags: org-mode

I am bad at elisp. I am trying to return to follow the idea of just getting everything from the orgfile, then pass it to R code to do easier analysis for me.

This works to generate only tags table

```
#+name: orgtable
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(let (orgtable)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (dolist (tag (org-get-tags))
       (push (list tag) orgtable))))
  orgtable)
#+end_src

#+begin_src R :var orgtable=orgtable
table(orgtable)

#+end_src
```

The above snippet works good. But I am trying to make a full table of the following columns

```
* TODO Task 1  :tag1:
 deadline:1-9-2021
* Waiting Task2
** DONE subtask :tag2:
::LOGBOOK::
completed: 7-7-2020
clock: start time- endtime => 2hours

#+begin_src
;;some script
#+End_src

#+ results
todo:task name:tags: schedule:deadline: clock: completed:
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
todo: task1   : tag1:        :1-9-2021:     :
waiting: task2:     :        :        :     :
done: subtask : tag2:        :        : 2hrs: 7-7-2020
```

I just don't know how to nest all of that in elisp code something like:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(let (orgtable)
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda ()
     (dolist (tag '((org-get-tags)
                    (org-get-todo-state)
                    (org-get-property-block)
                    ))
       (push (list tag) orgtable))))
  orgtable)
#+end_src
```

This just fails and not evaluated. Also it would be nice if I can extract every property on it's  own column.

Comment: What does each row of your table represent? All the info from one headline item? It would help if you added to your question an example Org mode file with a couple of entries, each containing the essential things you want to tabulate. Also add to your question the table that you expect to get from that example file.

Comment: @NickD Thank you, I have just clarifyed with example

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example Org file (based on what you provided but fixed up for syntax etc). It does not contain everything you want, but it does most of it - if I find time, I might come back for the rest:

```
#+TODO: TODO WAITING | DONE
#+STARTUP: logdrawer logdone

* TODO Task 1                                              :tag1:tag2:
DEADLINE: <2020-07-21 Tue>
 
* WAITING Task2
SCHEDULED: <2020-07-21 Tue>

** DONE subtask                                            :tag2:tag3:
CLOSED: [2020-07-21 Tue 15:50]

:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2020-07-21 Tue 15:47]--[2020-07-21 Tue 15:49] =>  0:02
:END:


* COMMENT Code
#+name: tags
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun entry-get (prop)
     (or (org-entry-get (point) prop) ""))

  (defun ndk/entries-table ()
     (interactive)
     (let ((tbl '(hline ("Name" "TODO" "Tags" "Scheduled" "Deadline" "Clock" "Closed"))))
       (org-clock-sum)
       (org-map-entries
        (lambda ()
          (push (list (entry-get "ITEM")
                      (entry-get "TODO")
                      (entry-get "TAGS")
                      (entry-get "SCHEDULED")
                      (entry-get "DEADLINE")
                      (entry-get "CLOCKSUM")
                      (entry-get "CLOSED"))
                      tbl))
        t
        'file
        'comment)
       (reverse tbl)))

   (ndk/entries-table)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: tags
| Name    | TODO    | Tags        | Scheduled        | Deadline         | Clock | Closed                 |
|---------+---------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------+------------------------|
| Task 1  | TODO    | :tag1:tag2: |                  | <2020-07-21 Tue> |       |                        |
| Task2   | WAITING |             | <2020-07-21 Tue> |                  |  0:02 |                        |
| subtask | DONE    | :tag2:tag3: |                  |                  |  0:02 | [2020-07-21 Tue 15:50] |
```

Some notes:

- I've added a `#+TODO:` setting, defining the `TODO` states, to make the file self-contained.
- I have not worried about the `LOGBOOK` stuff yet: that needs fixing up, both in the file and in the code.
- I've marked the `Code` section as a `COMMENT` and I make sure in the code to skip `COMMENT`ed sections from processing.
- The call to `org-map-entries` is limited to the current file and is instructed to skip `COMMENT` sections.
- The table is initialized with the column labels and a separator (see next item for why they are in the "wrong" order).
- We push new elements to the front of the table, so at the end we need to reverse it.
- If something is missing, it is shown in the table as `nil` because that's what `org-entry-get` returns. We can replace those calls with `(or (org-entry-get (point) "....") "")` to make it return an empty string instead.
- The special properties I use are documented [here](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Special-Properties) where you may find other interesting ones.

EDIT: Added the following changes:

- Added CLOCK and CLOSED entries in the file and the corresponding entries in the table. For the clock times to be shown correctly, you need to run the function `org-clock-sum` in the buffer before you try to retrieve the CLOCKSUM property, so I added a call to it.
- Added a small wrapper around `org-entry-get` to deal with the "nil vs empty string" problem above.
- Made the table production code into a function `ndk/entries-table` and added a call to it in the source block to produce the table.

I believe this completes everything you asked for in the original question.

For the question in your comment, there are a couple of ways of dealing with it: probably the easiest is to leave everything as is, but change the `ndk/entries-table function to take an argument, either a filename or a buffer. We then do everything in that buffer (but still produce the output in *this* buffer). Here's an implementation (for the whole file: you can't pick just a headline with this version, but I probably won't be able to do that any time soon - the implementation could be something like this though: make the headline a second optional argument, search in the chosen buffer for the desired headline, make sure you are in the right place, then call` org-map-enries`with a`tree`argument instead of a`file`argument`org-map-entries` is nothing if not flexible ;-) ):

```
#+name: tags
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun entry-get (prop)
     (or (org-entry-get (point) prop) ""))

  (defun ndk/entries-table (&optional file-or-buffer)
     (interactive)
     (cond
      ((null file-or-buffer)
       ;; just use the current buffer
       )
      ((bufferp file-or-buffer)
       (set-buffer file-or-buffer))
      (t
       (set-buffer (find-file-noselect file-or-buffer))))
     (let ((tbl '(hline ("Name" "TODO" "Tags" "Scheduled" "Deadline" "Clock" "Closed"))))
       (org-clock-sum)
       (org-map-entries
        (lambda ()
          (push (list (entry-get "ITEM")
                      (entry-get "TODO")
                      (entry-get "TAGS")
                      (entry-get "SCHEDULED")
                      (entry-get "DEADLINE")
                      (entry-get "CLOCKSUM")
                      (entry-get "CLOSED"))
                      tbl))
        t
        'file
        'comment)
       (reverse tbl)))

   (ndk/entries-table "./bar.org")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: tags
| Name              | TODO | Tags        | Scheduled        | Deadline         | Clock | Closed                 |
|-------------------+------+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------+------------------------|
| Task bar1         | TODO | :tag1:tag2: |                  | <2020-07-21 Tue> |       |                        |
| WAITING Task bar2 |      |             | <2020-07-21 Tue> |                  |  0:02 |                        |
| subtask bar       | DONE | :tag2:tag3: |                  |                  |  0:02 | [2020-07-21 Tue 15:50] |
```

BTW `bar.org` is more or less a copy of the original file with the titles changed, and no code included.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort, that was exactly what I was looking for so I can get out of emacs and have more flexability to pass for python or R

Comment: I have just few other thought; Can I run get for another file to specific headline and it's subheadlines. In other words, if I have file A with this script, can I get entries from another file B specifically, the subheadlines of a certain headline?!

Comment: Added the missing stuff (see the EDIT section in the answer for the notes on what changed). In general, it is preferred if you ask *one* question and you don't ask additional questions in the comments: you are encouraged to open a *new* question. However, you get the benefit of the doubt as a new user: I'll come back and answer the additional question this time (but it may take me a day or two). But remember this for next time!

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped me alot

Comment: You are welcome. I added a note with a suggested implementationf ot the headline-in-file part of your question.